# Run script after wake up

Tags: suspend, wakeup

I have a Toshiba notebook(Toshiba c50d a-133) and problems after waking up.
When I close the lid Ubuntu go to sleep mode. After opening, it wakes up, but sometimes mouse and keyboard don't work. Then I close and open again and it works.

Which scripts are run after opening the lid?
Is there a command to reset mouse and keyboard that I can add to such a script?

Comment: Here it is `cat  /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state`. This file stores the current state of your LID state(I think the value is: open and closed) so go ahead and write your script when you open the LID

Comment: Ah thanks a lot. Has anybody a script for this Problem? And how can i reset the keyboard / mouse?

Comment: And instead of resetting your keyboard and mouse you can refresh/reset the session. :)

Comment: hello kasia, can you tell me how to do this? the state is not the soluton. when the lid is opend, the reset must happend. any idea?